# How can I read and write specific values in a yaml document with unknown structure in go?

Tags: go, yaml

I'm working on a program that needs to read and write specific values in a yaml document with an unknown structure (ruling out loading it in as a struct) and access specific values to read or write within them. The indices for the values are user specified, therefore I can't use simple type assertions to access the data (if this is confusing just look at what the example at the bottom of `main`).

Currently I'm loading the file using yaml.v3 into a `map[interface{}]interface{}` and I've written a function `readYaml()` that takes a variadic `interface{}` parameter for the index of the value to be read. It only supports strings and ints but it can work out what's a map and what's a list and can read the value. The problem is it does it iteratively assigning each level of the structure to the `next` variable as it goes through the keys/indices passed into the function meaning the value cannot be written to.

I've also tried loading it as a `map[interface{}]*interface{}` but that only works for the first level, after that everything is still just an `interface{}` or whatever map and there's no way for me to get a pointer to the values to use for read and write access to the value.

Here's the code with a test at the end of the `main` function:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "log"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "errors"
)

type YAML map[interface{}]interface{}

// Throw appropriate error if the file does not exist
func checkFile(path string) {
    _, err := os.Stat(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.SetPrefix("file op: ")
        log.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("%s is an invalid file path", path))
    }
}


// Temp function to help debugging
func describe(i interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("(%v, %T)\n", i, i)
}


// Report an error with a prefix and the error contents
func reportError(prefix string, err error) {
    if err == nil { return }
    log.SetPrefix(fmt.Sprintf("ERROR %s", prefix))
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Read a value from a yaml document 
func (yamlIn YAML) readYaml(keys ...interface{}) (interface{}, error){
    var next interface{} = yamlIn
    // Iterate over passed in keys/indices
    for i, key := range keys {
        //key value map (YAML or map[string]interface{} type) or list ([]interface{})
        switch next.(type){
        case YAML:
            // Choose whether the key is a string or int to assert the type and get the next structure
            switch key.(type) {
            case string:
                next = next.(YAML)[key.(string)]
            case int:
                next = next.(YAML)[key.(int)]
            default:
                return nil, errors.New("string or int indices only")
            }
        case map[string]interface{}:
        // Choose whether the key is a string or int to assert the type and get the next structure
        switch key.(type) {
        case string:
            next = next.(map[string]interface{})[key.(string)]
        default:
            return nil, errors.New("cannot use non string for a string key")
        }
        case []interface{}:
            // Choose whether the key is a string or int to assertate the type and get the next strucutre
            switch key.(type) {
            case string:
                return nil, errors.New("cannot use string to index list") 
            case int:
                next = next.([]interface{})[key.(int)]
            default:
                return nil, errors.New("string or int indicies only")
        }
        default:
            return nil, errors.New("Unknown yaml structure") 
        }
        if next == nil {
            return nil, errors.New("Invalid index")
        }
        // If this is the last key return the value
        if i == len(keys)-1 {
            return next, nil
        }
    }
    return nil, errors.New("internal failure")
}

// --------------- Main ---------------

func main() {
    // Get and check files
    inputFiles := os.Args[1:]
    for _, path := range inputFiles {
        checkFile(path)
    }
    //fmt.Println("Hello there", strings.Join(inputFiles, " "))
 
    // Read file
    var files [][]byte 
    for _, path := range inputFiles {
        file, err := os.ReadFile(path)
        files = append(files, file) 
        reportError("file op: ", err) 
    }

    // Load yaml
    var yamls []YAML
    for _, file := range files {
        var yamlFile YAML
        err := yaml.Unmarshal(file, &yamlFile)
        yamls = append(yamls, yamlFile)
        reportError("yaml: ", err)
    }

    data, err := yamls[0].readYaml("INDEX")
    reportError("yaml: ", err)
    value, err := yamls[0].readYaml(data.([]interface{})...)
    reportError("yaml: ", err)
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

And the example YAML document used:

```yaml
CRAZY_FIRST_LEVEL:
  SECOND_LEVEL: string here
  WOW: wow
  LOSING_MY_MIND:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
EXAMPLE:
  FIRST:
    1: away
    UP: 1
  SECOND:
    WHAT: 1
    THE: 2
INDEX:
- EXAMPLE
- FIRST
- 1
```

The test demonstrates the ability to access data from an unknown structure using user defined keys and indices stored in the `INDEX` list and is able to correctly read the value `"away"` but I have no way to write to this value and I don't think with this method there is a way.

Any suggestions on a way I could read and write to the values?

Also coding practice suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I just skimmed your code: 1. You have to recurse down the tree. 2. I don't understand what you mean by saying "write to". map an slices are writable (so your problem is not the problem of addressability of the reflected values. 3. If you want to provide a function like `updateValue("newValue", "path", 3, "to", "thing", 1)` you will have to write basically the same function as readYaml (+recursion) and once you get to the "thing" slice you overwrite its index 1 with "newValue" (which should work as that element should be addressable).

Comment: I went and had a good pace under the stars after posting this and realized recursion was the solution. Upon trying to implement it I found myself in total type switch hell due to have to time switch for keys and the structures. Maybe I'm handling it poorly, but the code felt extremely verbose and unmaintainable in the event of adding further capability of data types and structures. I'm currently considering migrating the project to python to avoid the typing problems.

Comment: Yes. Working with dynamically typed data in a statically typed language will be complicated.